# How to create infinite treeview through sql recursive query

Tags: sql, recursion, treeview

Would appreciate if anybody help to create a recursive query to make infinite treeview. Sample data and output has been shown below for ready reference.

Contents of Details field will be root elements which do not have 'GroupCode'.

```
TABLE DATA (Example table name is 'Area')
=========================================

>GroupCode Code   Details (Continent/Country/Province or Division/City/Area/Street)
>========= ====   =================================================================
>          1      Asia
>          2      Europe
>          3      Africa
>          4      North America
>          5      South America
>          6      Australia
>          7      Antarctica
>1         8      Bangladesh
>1         9      India
>1         10     Pakistan
>8         11     Dhaka
>8         12     Chittagong
>12        13     Agrabad
>12        14     New-Market
>12        15     Halishahar
>9         16     West Bengal
>16        17     Kolkata (Calcutta)
>17        18     XYZ Area
>13        19     Road No. 111
>13        20     Road No. 222  
>
>Tree View
>========================================================
>-> (1) Asia
>      -> (8) Bangladesh
>              -> (12) Chittagong
>                      -> (13) Agrabad
>                              -> (19) Road No. 111
>                              -> (20) Road No. 222
>                      -> (14) New-Market
>                      -> (15) Halishahar
>
>      -> (9) India
>              -> (16) West Bengal
>                      -> (17) Kolkata
>                      -> (18) XYZ Area
>
```

Thanks,
Nowshad (Cell # +880-1713-442068)

Comment: What database? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server 2000 database